# PriorityQueue in Java not deterministic?

Tags: java, priority-queue

When I run the following priority queue test:

```
class Run {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueue<Entry> q = new PriorityQueue<>(8, Collections.reverseOrder(new Comparator<Entry>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Entry o1, Entry o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o1.getValue(), o2.getValue());
        }
    }));

    q.offer(new Entry(100));
    q.offer(new Entry(0));
    q.offer(new Entry(1));
    q.offer(new Entry(-1));
    q.offer(new Entry(0));
    q.offer(new Entry(1));
    q.offer(new Entry(-100));
    q.offer(new Entry(100));

    while (q.peek() != null) {
        System.out.println(q.poll());
    }
}

private static class Entry {

    private static int GLOBAL_ID = 0;

    private final int value, id;

    public Entry(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        id = GLOBAL_ID++;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entry[" + id + ", value = " + value + ']';
    }
}
```

}

I get the following result:

```
Entry[0, value = 100]
Entry[7, value = 100]
Entry[2, value = 1]
Entry[5, value = 1]
Entry[4, value = 0]
Entry[1, value = 0]
Entry[3, value = -1]
Entry[6, value = -100]
```

I expect equal elements to be output in the same order as they are being input, so when entry 0 is offered before entry 7, it is also polled before 7 is polled. But why is entry 4 suddenly polled before the 1? Is it the erroneous `Comparator` or does `PriorityQueue` not guarantee a deterministic behaviour?

Comment: The comparator only defines an ordering on value, nothing else. As Rich L's answer points to the documentation, ties are broken arbitrarily. Update your comparator to account for the timestamp of object insertion/ID of the objects.

Comment: See [Making a Java PriorityQueue into a stable priority queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617098/making-a-java-priorityqueue-into-a-stable-priority-queue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is non-deterministic.

From the [documentation for PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

> If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of
>   those elements -- ties are broken arbitrarily.

Comment: As an addition to this: there is an example implementation for a timestamped entry that makes the standard prio queue deterministic. It can be found in [PriorityBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html)'s doc. Not very intuitive if you ask me, but meh.