# How to use insertion order to break tier for PriorityQueue or minHeap?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I met this question in an interview. The interviewer gave me an `class Student` like following:

```java
class Student {
    int age;
    String name;

    public Student(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "age=" + age +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

He wanted me to implement a `PriorityQueue` with smallest student's age be highest priority. If there is a tier, he wanted me to use insertion order to break tier, i.e. earliest element with highest priority.

My idea is to use following warper class to encode infomation of timestamp.

```java
class Element implements Comparable<Element> {
    Student student;
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public Element(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Element o) {
        int cmp = Integer.compare(student.age, o.student.age);
        return cmp == 0 ? Long.compare(timestamp, o.timestamp) : cmp;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<Element> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Student t1 = new Student(2, "a");
        Student t2 = new Student(2, "b");
        Student t3 = new Student(1, "c");

        pq.offer(new Element(t1));
        pq.offer(new Element(t2));
        pq.offer(new Element(t3));

        System.out.println(pq.poll().student);
        System.out.println(pq.poll().student);
        System.out.println(pq.poll().student);
    }
}
```

However, the interviewer wanted me not to use timestamp infomation, then I cannot come up with a concrete solution in interview. I can only guess some ideas:

(1) it may require me to use hybrid data structure(combine something like `LinkedHashMap`/`LinkedList` and `PriorityQueue`)

(2) it may require me to implement personal binary minHeap which can break tier by using insertion order. I know how to implement minHeap using percolateUp and percolateDown. However, I never heard I can just hack the binary heap's implemention to use insertion order in algorithm class.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis` does not guarantee returning different numbers each time you call it. Neither does `System.nanoTime`, for that matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a Java PriorityQueue into a stable priority queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617098/making-a-java-priorityqueue-into-a-stable-priority-queue)

Comment: @kaya3 Thank you so mcuh. First learn the caveat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to the following solution:

- implement a container that wraps a `PriorityQueue` and track the *count* of element added to the queue;
- create wrapper over the `Student` class, which I implemented as a `record`.

```
public record StudentWrapper(Student student, long queueId) {}
```

```
public class OrderedQueue {
    private static final Comparator<StudentWrapper> BY_AGE_AND_QUEUE_ID =
            Comparator.<StudentWrapper>comparingInt(studWr -> studWr.student().getAge())
                    .thenComparingLong(StudentWrapper::queueId);

    private Queue<StudentWrapper> queue;
    private long count;

    public OrderedQueue() {
        this.queue = new PriorityQueue<>(BY_AGE_AND_QUEUE_ID);
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        queue.offer(new StudentWrapper(student, count++));
    }

    public Optional<Student> removeStudent() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(queue.poll())
                .map(StudentWrapper::student);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return queue.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

**main**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OrderedQueue orderedQueue = new OrderedQueue();
        orderedQueue.addStudent(new Student(1, "foo"));
        orderedQueue.addStudent(new Student(2, "a"));
        orderedQueue.addStudent(new Student(2, "b"));
        orderedQueue.addStudent(new Student(1, "bar"));
        orderedQueue.addStudent(new Student(1, "c"));

        while (!orderedQueue.isEmpty()) {
            orderedQueue.removeStudent().ifPresent(System.out::println);
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
Student{age=1, name='foo'}
Student{age=1, name='bar'}
Student{age=1, name='c'}
Student{age=2, name='a'}
Student{age=2, name='b'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign a sequence number in order of arrival. This requires just replacing the line where you assign 'timestamp' with assigning the next value of a monotonically increasing sequence number.

```
static long nextSequence = 0;
long sequence = nextSequence++;
```

and replace your use of 'timestamp' with 'sequence'.

I regard this as superior to use of currentTimeMillis since (a) it allows processing of arrival rates higher than one every millisecond, and (b) the current time is not guaranteed against going backwards.

A long integer has plenty of headroom. If you're generating a new id every 100 nS, it'll overflow after about 30,000 years.